# Алгоритм шифрования/дешифрования базы данных

Tags: c#, алгоритм, криптография

(C#) Разработайте
алгоритм, по которому Вы планируете
выполнять шифрование/дешифрование базы
данных либо выберите один из существующих
алгоритмов.
Разработанный
алгоритм шифрования может быть простым,
например, смещение символа в ASCII-таблице
(если шифруемый символ А, то он становится
символом Б) . Либо смещение может зависеть
от номера символа в строке (3-й символ
смещается на 2 символа вправо – А
становится В, а 5-й на 3 влево – Е становится
В и т. д.) .

Comment: @sarvan, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: я сделал но он у меня не идеально работает шифровать шифрует а расшифровка вводит вообще другие значения. как вам я могу скинуть исходник?

Comment: вставляйте код в текст вопроса (полагаю, интересующий вас участок не займет десяток страниц)

Comment: @sarvan выложите код в вашем сообщении и нажмите на кнопку `{}` - код отформатируется.

Comment: @sarvan [pastebin.com]() для длинных паст

> не идеально работает шифровать шифрует а расшифровка вводит вообще другие значения

с точки зрения криптографии это "не работает вообще"

Comment: http://pastebin.com/GMgZ0PzG

Comment: четыреста с лишним строк сплошных if-else? Поверьте, читать эту портянку найдется мало желающих.  Вы что-нибудь слышали про коллекции, Dictionary тот же к примеру? Воспользуйся вы ими, могли бы сократить свой код  строк до 30

Comment: @sarvan вынужден заметить, что весь смысл программирования в том, чтобы автоматизировать задачки и кратко написать алгоритмы. С этим у вас, кхм, проблемации.

Comment: если бы я знал я давно сделал. ну а так я прощу помощи

Comment: У вас детсадовская реализация алгоритма Цезаря :) Ну то есть подстановка вместо одного символа другого. Но вообще это ужас. Вам лучше не заниматься программированием.

Comment: я знаю( но что уж поделать обратного пути нет)

Comment: >если бы я знал я давно сделал. ну а так я прощу помощи

ваш код очень уж большой и скучный, поэтому совет тут можно дать только один - прочитайте в документации про Dictionary в C# и воспользуйтесь ими. Так вы сможете уложить весь этот бардак всего в несколько строк и сэкономите стране полтонны бумаги на печати отчета по своей лабораторной. А сделав этот код короче, вы сможете сделать его понятным и более удобным для правок? и, вполне вероятно, ошибка в логике станет гораздо более очевидной

Answer (score 3):

Пара комментариев по заданию, которые просто не влезают в обычный комментарий

> Разработанный алгоритм шифрования может быть простым, например, смещение символа в ASCII-таблице

Как минимум слово ASCII должно вызвать определенные мысли и привести к значительному облегчению задачи. В таблице ASCII нет русскоязычных символов, и все описанные там символы умещаются в один байт. Таким образом, шифрация и дешифрация сводятся к банальной смене значения символа (мы к этому еще вернемся).

> Либо смещение может зависеть от номера символа в строке (3-й символ смещается на 2 символа вправо – А становится В, а 5-й на 3 влево – Е становится В и т. д.) .

Здесь опять же говорится про смещение - не про замену символа другим по какой-то таблице! - и описывается алгоритм, как это должно происходить. В этом алгоритме вообще нет поиска соответствия одного символа другому - есть только поиск соответствия положения символа в строке.

Теперь что до ASCII и байтов. Каждый символ, как известно, может быть представлен набором байтов; для ASCII-символов это просто один байт. И суть задания состоит в том, чтобы работать с каждым символом, как с байтом (не доходил до такого в сишарпе, но это явно не сложнее, чем обычный каст; в просто си даже кастовать бы не пришлось), и просто прибавлять/отнимать от него единицу, двойку, или что там указано в задаче, не забыв при этом проверить, возможно ли переполнение и предусмотрев его, если оно возможно.

Еще раз специально подчеркну, что результирующая программа ***не должна даже знать***, с каким именно символом работает - она тупо смещает код этого символа и следит за тем, чтобы результирующий код не попал в рамки недозволенного, а какой именно это символ - неважно.